# Cygwin ctrl-number not working (in cli emacs)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, emacs, mintty

Cygwin ctrl-number is not working in cli emacs. I disabled the mintty options for keyboard shortcuts, so now `^-` does work the same as `^u -1`. Still, ctrl-number shortcuts do not work in emacs. `^4 ^x o` for example should advance the window focus by 4, the same as keying `^x o` 4 times. Instead, I get a single `u` character inserted into the current buffer and then the frame focus advances one place forward. This is the same for all number keys. Arrow keys work in emacs so the escape character and timing-based detection of escape sequences appears to be working correctly. My .emacs has a handful of bindings but all in the `^c letter` realm (reserved for user bindings).

Running `hexdump -C` in bash and typing `^2` yields a null character, while the other numbers produce `1b 5b 31 3b 35 7x` where `x` is the number typed. (hexdump on ubuntu produces a raw 0x31 code, apparently ignoring ctrl.) In contrast, `^q ^1` in emacs (and then  switching to `hexl-mode`) shows the sequence emacs is receiving is `1b 5b 34 39 3b 35 75`.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to emacs.SE and SuperUser. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I will happily delete one as soon as the other gets an answer. I gave superuser two days with zero answers or comments before branching out.